# how to create shared weights layer in multiple input models with no grads

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to create a model with 2 inputs x and y. And I want make loss function only concerned about x. So the model can optimize former layer only with x. But now even the loss is only concerned about x, the optimazition will still calculate x and y in the former layer.

I have tried to make y to y.detach() to make grads stop. But that won't work. And I also want to try to create new shared weights layer, but I don't know how to do that.

```
def forward(self, x, y=None):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x)
    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    x = self.layer4(x)
    y = self.conv1(y)
    y = self.bn1(y)
    y = self.maxpool(y)
    y = self.layer1(y)
    return x, y
```

Comment: when `y.detach()` - do you detach the input `y` or the output `y`?

Comment: I put the input y.detach not the out put

Answer (score 0):

What you did should work, you just need to put your `y.detach()` at the end, and if the loss doesn't contain `y` it shouldn't modify the weights through `y` anyway.

```
def forward(self, x, y=None):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x)
    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    x = self.layer4(x)
    y = self.conv1(y)
    y = self.bn1(y)
    y = self.maxpool(y)
    y = self.layer1(y)
    return x, y.detach()
```

Comment: I will try to do that at the output part.

Comment: And even if the loss func not contain y, model still optimize through x and y. Because the model former part have x and y as input, the model's gradient will consider both of them in the former layer.

Comment: and I have just tried. Only use y.detach() at return won't work

Comment: @ZiyueZhang That shouldn't be the case, if y is not in the loss function, there is no way the there can be any gradients from y, same in the case where the output is y.detach(), there must be something else wrong. When you say it "doesn't work", how do you know that exactly?

Comment: I know it by check the accuracy. I think the reason is Pytorch may calc gradient by all input in the forward layer if this layer is in the training mode. Only the variable stop gradient wont work. Such as the loss is F(x), but the input is x and y. The gradient will flow these 2 in the training forward layer. We must stop the gradient in the layer. You can check my answer below. I use that trick to do the stopping gradient in the layer.

Comment: `eval` and `train` just change the use of the batchnorm, they have no effect on propagation or not of gradients

Comment: The eval and train will stop the gradient of these layers when doing the forward.

Answer (score 0):

I use a little trick to solve the problem at the end. I will try the y.detach() at the output later. now I solve this by stopping the gradient manually. The code:

```
    def forward(self, x, y):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    # x = self.relu(x)    # add missed relu
    x = self.maxpool(x)
    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    x = self.layer4(x)


    self.eval()
    y = self.conv1(y)
    y = self.bn1(y)
    y = self.maxpool(y)
    y = self.layer1(y)
    self.train()

    return x, y
```